# Problem with sum() in QDSL CaseBuilder in Java

Tags: java, aggregate, querydsl

I get error when running unit test using a code where this part with CaseBuilder() is used in the list().

```
  new CaseBuilder()
    .when((((vTVw.value.abs().goe(20)))
       .or(null)))
    .then(1)
    .otherwise(0)
    .sum()
```

Here is the part from error:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: SUM or AVG on wrong data type
> for "SUM(CASE WHEN (ABS(T_VW.VALUE) >= ?1) THEN ?2 ELSE ?3 END)"; SQL
> statement:

When I remove sum() there is no error. Also the same code works fine in the main production code, but fails only in unit test run. What am I missing here? I tried coalesce, but it didn't work. I searched for  the error message online but couldn't find anything related to my case.

Answer (score 0):

H2 cant deduce the expression type from parameters. You have to explicitly cast the parameters. Try: `.then(Expressions.asNumber(1).castToNum(Integer.class)).otherwise(0)`.